# Calculate the angles of an n- angle (plus comparison)

Tags: java, math, angle

I am trying to calculate the angle between points of an n-angle shape. There are 2 arrays which hold x and y coordinates. I keep getting an error with P13 and I can't figure out why. Does anyone know a reason?

```
public class Ugao {

    public static int nizovi(double[]a , double[]b , double alfa) {
        int BrStr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            double P12,P13, P23;
            P12 = duzina(a[i+1], b[i+1], a[i], b[i]);
            P13 = duzina(a[i+1], b[i+1], a[i+2], b[i+2]); // pisemo prvo i+1 jer je to vertex tacka, ona koja je u centru ugla, zato nije od i
            P23 = duzina(a[i], b[i], a[i+2], b[i+2]);

            double x = ugao(P12, P13, P23);
            if(x > alfa) {
                System.out.print( "Stranica : " + "( " + a[i] + "," + b[i] + " )" + "( " + a[i+1] + "," + b[i+1] + " )" + " & ");
                System.out.println("( " + a[i+1] + "," + b[i+1] + " )" + "( " + a[i+2] + "," + b[i+2] + " )");
                System.out.println();
                BrStr++;
            }
        }
        return BrStr;
    }


    public static double ugao (double P12, double P13, double P23) {
        return Math.acos((Math.pow(P12, 2) + Math.pow(P13, 2) - Math.pow(P23, 2))/(2 * P12 * P13));
    }

    public static double duzina (double vertexX1, double vertexY1, double x2, double y2) {
        return  Math.sqrt(Math.pow((vertexX1-x2),2)+ Math.pow((vertexY1-y2), 2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        double a[] = {12,25,3};
        double b[] = {11,20,5};

        nizovi(a, b, 45);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of array range.

For example, if `length = 4` array contains indexes `0..3`, but at the last cycle run with `i=3` expression `a[i+2]` wants element `a[5]`

You can use modulo arithmetic to get next vertices indexes

```
 current: i
 next: (i+1)%length
 nextnext: (i+2)%length
```

Comment: Thank you for correction and suggestion! That's a neat fix! :)